# view a PNG file in 24 pixel monochrome

Tags: images, gimp

I want to make a monochrome bitmap from a PNG image. I will manually convert the monochrome image into bits which is easy to do. For example if a row of pixels is supposed to be `on, off, on, off, on, off, on, off` that can be represented by the binary code `10101010` which is the hexadecimal code `AA`.

[image: bell image 24 by 24]

The image file properties show that it is a 24 x 24 pixel image.

[image: image properties]

When I view the file it creates the impression that it is not a 24 x 24 pixel monochrome image. When I use Ubuntu's default application "Image Viewer" to look at the image it seems to display an illusion with shades of grey and it seems to use more than 24 bits per side in order to do so and the background is represented by something other than whitespace. Here's a screen shot of what "Image Viewer" shows me. (Edit: It might be 24 bits per side but it's hard to tell because I can imagine the grey effect can be achieved with more pixels but I imagine it could also be achieved by varying the brightness.)

[image: image viewer screenshot]

How would I view this icon as a 24 x 24 pixel monochrome bitmap using readily available tools such as conversion websites or Gimp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is image has an alpha channel. In other words, besides the usual Red/Green/Blue, a 4th byte indicates the pixel opacity. This is in particular used on the edge pixels of the bell, they have a partial opacity so that when the PNG is put over a background of any color, these edge pixels blend partially with the background to create a visually smooth edge.

To see it as a true black and white image, you would just put it over a white layer and merge the result. But the resulting image will contain grey pixels on the edges of the bell.

Comment: Just to add, the checkerboard pattern is how a transparent area is indicated.

Comment: I need a monochrome image. Is there a way to get rid of the grey completely?

Comment: Merge it into a white background and threshold the result